# How to use SQLite in rollback mode?

Tags: python, sqlite, nfs

Hi I'm building a simple system by python with SQLite, I set a db file on NFS to allow writing by only one user but with multiple readers from different machines, all I need is to know how to implement isolation by locking the database file and preventing any reads by other database connections while each write transaction is underway, that's a sample of my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\الموارد البشرية & الرعاية الطبية\HR2.db")
conn.rollback()
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO connected VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (record[1], dateYY, first_date, final_date))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `sqlite` documentation

> the reader is only able to see complete committed transactions from the writer. Partial changes by the writer that have not been committed are invisible to the reader.